# Parse json return non valid object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

i want to parse Json Feed from my localhost

http://localhost/hardfeed.json
this Json file content is ::

```
{
    "bpi": {
        "2018-04-14": 8003.6813,
        "2018-04-15": 8357.0375,
        "2018-04-16": 8051.345,
        "2018-04-17": 7890.15,
        "2018-04-18": 8163.69,
        "2018-04-19": 8273.7413,
        "2018-04-20": 8863.5025,
        "2018-04-21": 8917.5963,
        "2018-04-22": 8792.83,
        "2018-04-23": 8938.3038,
        "2018-04-24": 9652.1563,
        "2018-04-25": 8864.0875,
        "2018-04-26": 9278.9975,
        "2018-04-27": 8978.3325,
        "2018-04-28": 9342.4713,
        "2018-04-29": 9392.0313,
        "2018-04-30": 9244.3225,
        "2018-05-01": 9067.715,
        "2018-05-02": 9219.8638,
        "2018-05-03": 9734.675,
        "2018-05-04": 9692.7175,
        "2018-05-05": 9826.5975,
        "2018-05-06": 9619.1438,
        "2018-05-07": 9362.5338,
        "2018-05-08": 9180.1588,
        "2018-05-09": 9306,
        "2018-05-10": 9014.615,
        "2018-05-11": 8406.175,
        "2018-05-12": 8467.6563,
        "2018-05-13": 8688.0288,
        "2018-05-14": 8675.2063
    },
    "disclaimer": "This Test is generated from Localhost",
    "time": {
        "updated": "May 15, 2018 00:03:00 UTC",
        "updatedISO": "2018-05-15T00:03:00+00:00"
    }
}
```

when parsing the file data i got a non valid result without quotes for the bpi object
 [image: parse non valid data]

this is my JS method

```
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/hardfeed.json', function(data) {

console.log(data) ; 


    });
```

Comment: That is not invalid response. that's the proper result

Comment: How to get the of value of key e.g obj["2018-04-14"] ?

Comment: as @HarshPatel said, the data you're printing is as expected. `getJSON` will convert the returned output as a javascript object. You should just try to use that data now or iterate over the `data.bpi` for instance.

Comment: Object.keys(data.bpi)

Comment: ok Thank you so much my problem is solved

Comment: All you need to do is to use bracket notation. `data.bpi["2018-04-14"]`

Comment: @baao return undefined